# Please provide AnyOfferChangedNotification callback response

Tags: amazon-mws

Please anyone provide the sample xml response with sample data for the **AnyOfferChangedNotification** from amazon mws queue. I could able to find scheme of it ie http://g-ec2.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/mwsportal/doc/en_US/subscriptions/AnyOfferChangedNotification.xsd

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer, could be helpful for others.

https://gist.github.com/hakanensari/9f3e14d18a44f0d1c153

```
<Notification>
 <NotificationMetaData>
   <NotificationType>AnyOfferChanged</NotificationType>
   <PayloadVersion>1.0</PayloadVersion>
   <UniqueId>14baf090-6a81-4d13-b1ad-340363d569d8</UniqueId>
   <PublishTime>2014-02-23T11:35:40.497Z</PublishTime>
   <SellerId>MERCHANT_ID_1</SellerId>
   <MarketplaceId>A2EUQ1WTGCTBG2</MarketplaceId>
 </NotificationMetaData>
 <NotificationPayload>
   <AnyOfferChangedNotification>
     <OfferChangeTrigger>
       <MarketplaceId>A2EUQ1WTGCTBG2</MarketplaceId>
       <ASIN>0205487157</ASIN>
       <ItemCondition>used</ItemCondition>
       <TimeOfOfferChange>2014-02-23T11:35:40.087Z</TimeOfOfferChange>
     </OfferChangeTrigger>
     <Summary>
       <NumberOfOffers>
         <OfferCount condition="new" fulfillmentChannel="Merchant">5</OfferCount>
         <OfferCount condition="used" fulfillmentChannel="Merchant">10</OfferCount>
       </NumberOfOffers>
       <LowestPrices>
         <LowestPrice condition="new" fulfillmentChannel="Merchant">
           <LandedPrice>
             <Amount>50.68</Amount>
             <CurrencyCode>CAD</CurrencyCode>
           </LandedPrice>
           <ListingPrice>
             <Amount>44.19</Amount>
             <CurrencyCode>CAD</CurrencyCode>
           </ListingPrice>
           <Shipping>
             <Amount>6.49</Amount>
             <CurrencyCode>CAD</CurrencyCode>
           </Shipping>
         </LowestPrice>
         <LowestPrice condition="used" fulfillmentChannel="Merchant">
           <LandedPrice>
             <Amount>24.04</Amount>
             <CurrencyCode>CAD</CurrencyCode>
           </LandedPrice>
           <ListingPrice>
             <Amount>17.55</Amount>
             <CurrencyCode>CAD</CurrencyCode>
           </ListingPrice>
           <Shipping>
             <Amount>6.49</Amount>
             <CurrencyCode>CAD</CurrencyCode>
           </Shipping>
         </LowestPrice>
       </LowestPrices>
       <ListPrice>
         <Amount>101.07</Amount>
         <CurrencyCode>CAD</CurrencyCode>
       </ListPrice>
       <BuyBoxEligibleOffers>
         <OfferCount condition="new" fulfillmentChannel="Merchant">2</OfferCount>
         <OfferCount condition="used" fulfillmentChannel="Merchant">4</OfferCount>
       </BuyBoxEligibleOffers>
     </Summary>
     <Offers>
       <Offer>
         <SellerId>MERCHANT_ID_1</SellerId>
         <SubCondition>acceptable</SubCondition>
         <SellerFeedbackRating>
           <SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>87</SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>
           <FeedbackCount>7768</FeedbackCount>
         </SellerFeedbackRating>
         <ShippingTime minimumHours="24" maximumHours="48"/>
         <ListingPrice>
           <Amount>17.55</Amount>
           <CurrencyCode>CAD</CurrencyCode>
         </ListingPrice>
         <Shipping>
           <Amount>6.49</Amount>
           <CurrencyCode>CAD</CurrencyCode>
         </Shipping>
         <ShipsFrom>
           <Country>US</Country>
           <State>IN</State>
         </ShipsFrom>
         <IsFulfilledByAmazon>false</IsFulfilledByAmazon>
         <ConditionNotes>Usually ships within 1-2 business days, please allow 4-14 business days for delivery, ship</ConditionNotes>
         <IsExpeditedShippingAvailable>false</IsExpeditedShippingAvailable>
         <IsFeaturedMerchant>false</IsFeaturedMerchant>
         <ShipsDomestically>true</ShipsDomestically>
         <ShipsInternationally>true</ShipsInternationally>
       </Offer>
       <Offer>
         <SellerId>MERCHANT_ID_2</SellerId>
         <SubCondition>very_good</SubCondition>
         <SellerFeedbackRating>
           <SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>97</SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>
           <FeedbackCount>8899</FeedbackCount>
         </SellerFeedbackRating>
         <ShippingTime minimumHours="24" maximumHours="48"/>
         <ListingPrice>
           <Amount>118.10</Amount>
           <CurrencyCode>CAD</CurrencyCode>
         </ListingPrice>
         <Shipping>
           <Amount>6.49</Amount>
           <CurrencyCode>CAD</CurrencyCode>
         </Shipping>
         <ShipsFrom>
           <Country>US</Country>
           <State>FL</State>
         </ShipsFrom>
         <IsFulfilledByAmazon>false</IsFulfilledByAmazon>
         <ConditionNotes>Satisfaction Guaranteed! Delivery in 1-2 weeks!</ConditionNotes>
         <IsExpeditedShippingAvailable>false</IsExpeditedShippingAvailable>
         <IsFeaturedMerchant>false</IsFeaturedMerchant>
         <ShipsDomestically>true</ShipsDomestically>
         <ShipsInternationally>true</ShipsInternationally>
       </Offer>
     </Offers>
     </AnyOfferChangedNotification>
   </NotificationPayload>
 </Notification>
```